# CoffeeScript functions

Tags: coffeescript

I was reading this smooth CoffeeScript book and it had a code

```
confirm 'Shall we, then?', (answer) -> show answer
```

This is supposed to get the answer from the confirm and show it / I changed the 'show' to console.log and it doesn't seem to execute it. what am I missing.

thanks

Comment: Changed _what_ to `console.log`? Your question is unclear regarding what unexpected thing is happening to confuse you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`confirm()` doesn't take a callback. Unless this guy made his own confirm function, that won't work. The cs for that compiles to

```
confirm("Shall we, then?", function(answer) {
  return console.log(answer);
});
```

`confirm()` returns `true` or `false`, so you can just use it as a conditional.

```
console.log "They answered yes" if confirm "Shall we, then?"
```